# Debian VPS server - backup

Tags: debian, backup, ftp

I'm trying to backup my VPS-server (debian) to new Router FTP server.

---

### Past (stable backup to my PC):

I had backup of my VPS-server to my home-PC over Internet. 
I used "Filesystem Backup" with cron (everyday) running by VPS-server using command similar to:

```
tar (child): test@drozdo.no-ip.biz\:testdir/dbbackup.gz
```

This solution worked successfully.

---

### Now (backup to Router supporting FTP Server):

Few day ago I bought router (TP-LINK WR1043) with FTP Server support, works with external HDD (by USB). If I connect to FTP Server (of router) from normal PC over internet, everything WORKS. But if i run backup from VPS-server, write this error:

```
FTP write failed : STOR testdir/2014-03-10_13-45_dbbackup.gz failed : Permission denied.

tar (child): test@drozdo.no-ip.biz\:testdir/2014-03-10_13-45_dbbackup.gz: Cannot write: Operation not permitted
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: test@drozdo.no-ip.biz\:testdir/2014-03-10_13-45_dbbackup.gz: Cannot write: Broken pipe
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

> - I dont understand why permission is denied.

---

*Login data to FTP server (turned ON for test):*
- host: drozdo.no-ip.biz
- user: test
- password: test1

Thank you for responses